# MySQL Full Text Search - multiple search for the same field

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have these table:

```
|   ID   | detail_id |       detail_value       | book_id |

| ------ | --------- |------------------------- | ------- |

| 1      | 11        | Warszawa                 | 103     |

| 2      | 14        | Grażyńskiego             | 123     |

| 3      | 11        | st.Warszawa m            | 123     |

| 4      | 14        | Michała Grażyńskiego     | 222     |

| 5      | 11        | Warszawa                 | 222     |

| 6      | 14        | Katowicka                | 103     |

| 7      | 9         | 923                      | 23      |

| 8      | 12        | 432424                   | 23      |

| 9      | 14        | Przykładowa              | 23      |

| 10     | 11        | Warszawa                 | 23      |
```

`detail_id`: 14 - this is street name, 11 - this is city name (other is not important).

And now, I have two phrases (which are writed by user on my website):
`warszawa` (detail_id: 11 - this is city name) and `grażyń` (detail_id: 14 - this is the part of street name).

And now I want to get all records where `book_id` is 123 and 222, because these records contains phrase `warszawa` as detail_id = 11 and phrase `grażyń` as detail_id = 14.

Here is my sql request:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

The problem is - this request return no results. When I try use part of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

OR:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this works fine but when I want to combine these queries, I got no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extss but youtrr query actually gives back zero rows back

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `table` (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `detail_id` INTEGER,
>   `detail_value` VARCHAR(20),
>   `book_id` INTEGER
>   ,
>        FULLTEXT idx (detail_value)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `table`
>   (`ID`, `detail_id`, `detail_value`, `book_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '11', 'Warszawa', '103'),
>   ('2', '14', 'Grażyńskiego', '123'),
>   ('3', '11', 'st.Warszawa m', '123'),
>   ('4', '14', 'Michała Grażyńskiego', '222'),
>   ('5', '11', 'Warszawa', '222'),
>   ('6', '14', 'Katowicka', '103'),
>   ('7', '9', '923', '23'),
>   ('8', '12', '432424', '23'),
>   ('9', '14', 'Przykładowa', '23'),
>   ('10', '11', 'Warszawa', '23');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
> AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*rażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
> ```

> ```
> ID | detail_id | detail_value | book_id
> -: | --------: | :----------- | ------:
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | detail_id | detail_value  | book_id
> -: | --------: | :------------ | ------:
>  1 |        11 | Warszawa      |     103
>  3 |        11 | st.Warszawa m |     123
>  5 |        11 | Warszawa      |     222
> 10 |        11 | Warszawa      |      23
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 1 as test FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*rażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
> ```
>
> ```
> | test |
> | ---: |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51ee5074ba1f46cfe881f51fa9629357)*

changing the second query

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
> AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
> ```

> ```
> ID | detail_id | detail_value  | book_id
> -: | --------: | :------------ | ------:
>  1 |        11 | Warszawa      |     103
>  3 |        11 | st.Warszawa m |     123
> 10 |        11 | Warszawa      |      23
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | detail_id | detail_value  | book_id
> -: | --------: | :------------ | ------:
>  1 |        11 | Warszawa      |     103
>  3 |        11 | st.Warszawa m |     123
>  5 |        11 | Warszawa      |     222
> 10 |        11 | Warszawa      |      23
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 1 as test FROM `table` WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
> ```
>
> ```
> | test |
> | ---: |
> |    1 |
> |    1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a3af5280a99760d353a32f1ee9ff170)*

Ok as further constraint both have to have the same bookng _id

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` t1 
> WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
> AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
> FROM `table` 
> WHERE detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
> AND book_id = t1.book_id)
> ```

> ```
> ID | detail_id | detail_value  | book_id
> -: | --------: | :------------ | ------:
>  3 |        11 | st.Warszawa m |     123
>  5 |        11 | Warszawa      |     222
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf9b035300a733d40c038907d0580bb5)*

Comment: change `rażyń` for `grażyń` and now it will be works fine but only when you use part of these queries. So this query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE));` not work but when you use ONE MATCH...AGAINST, it work fine. Together it doesn't work.

Comment: see the example with graintz of course it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a3af5280a99760d353a32f1ee9ff170

Comment: OK, I see now. But there is one problem - I need to get only these results, where book_id is the same. So book_number=222 (and 123) contains phrase `warszawa` as city name (detail_id=11) and phrase `grażyń` as part of street name also.

Comment: add another where condition see changed answer

Comment: That look's good but what about more parameters? For example `detail_id` = 9 as house number and `detail_id` = 12 as post code? I have 38 parameters as total, so I need universal solution.

Comment: then you need to add 38 extists

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is - this request return no results.

you wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (detail_id = 11 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (detail_id = 14 AND MATCH (detail_value) AGAINST ('*grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

in best case means:

```
WHERE (detail_id = 11) AND (detail_id = 14)
```

How to have both `(detail_id = 11)` and `(detail_id = 14)` in one row?

you must use join and then filter base on your columns:

```
select 
street.book_id,
street.detail_value as street_name,
city.detail_value as city_name
from
(select * from `table` where detail_id = 14) as street
join (select * from `table` where detail_id = 11) as city on city.book_id=street.book_id
```

result is:

| book_id | street_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | Katowicka | Warszawa |
| 123 | Grażyńskiego | st.Warszawa m |
| 222 | Michała Grażyńskiego | Warszawa |
| 23 | Przykładowa | Warszawa |

now you can filter it easily

[test it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f6bc7675dcb4eb7a08c55230524cec2)

```
select 
street.book_id,
street.detail_value as street_name,
city.detail_value as city_name
from
(select * from `table` where detail_id = 14 and MATCH (detail_value ) AGAINST ('*grażyń*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as street
join (select * from `table` where detail_id = 11 and MATCH (detail_value ) AGAINST ('*warszawa*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) as city on city.book_id=street.book_id
```

| book_id | street_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **123** | Grażyńskiego | st.Warszawa m |
| **222** | Michała Grażyńskiego | Warszawa |

note: Decide based on the size of your table

Comment: That look's good but what about more parameters? For example `detail_id` = 9 as house number and `detail_id` = 12 as post code? I have 38 parameters as total, so I need universal solution.

Comment: @Pavvcio you said `other is not important`, However, you can use multiple joins.
I do not know what your ultimate goal is.